# Array of structures not storing data as expected

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I wrote the following code which is supposed to read an input, n = number of people, then create an array of structs the size of n, then read the info of each person and finally print all the info in order.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct person {
        char name[51];
        int age;
    };
    struct person list[n];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", list[n].name);
        scanf("%d", &list[n].age);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Name: %s - Age: %d\n", list[i].name, list[i].age);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I compiled it using GCC on Ubuntu, executed and provided the following inputs:

```
1
Lucia
60
```

But instead of getting `Name: Lucia - Age: 60` on the terminal, I'm getting `Name: �rI�� - Age: 32766` which I believe is random trash in the computer's memory. I'm using the same treatment of arrays of structs I see in some web pages and in my college's material, so why doesn't it store the data properly?

Comment: Typo: `scanf("%s", list[n].name);` -> `scanf("%s", list[i].name);`

Comment: That's right. I read and re-read the code but couldn't detect it for some reason. I fixed it and the issue is gone, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used i in your for loop, you should end up calling it as well in your scanfs not n. Change it to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%s", list[i].name);
    scanf("%d", &list[i].age);
}
```

and this should do the trick!